# Is there a way to increase the resolution?

Tags: quantum-conundrum

The game won't let me increase my resolution over 1280x1040.  I have become spoiled by modern graphics.  Is there a way to increase the resolution over this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just [found a solution](http://forums.steamgames.com/forums/showpost.php?p=31259668&postcount=5) that doesn't require any config-file hacks:

Right-click the game in steam --> properties --> launch options, set them to

```
-resx=1600 -resy=900
```

for 1600x900.

*However, when I did this, the bottom of my screen became tinted purple.  There doesn't seem to be any way to fix this other than turning the resolution back down, which I ended up doing :\*

---

Alternatively, if the above doesn't work for you *(or you* want *to use a config-file hack)*, open up the file

```
%USERPROFILE%\My Documents\My Games\UnrealEngine3\TryGame\Config\TryEngine.ini
```

in a text-editor like notepad.  Find the lines that begin with `resx` and `resy`, and change the values to whatever you'd like.  There have been [mixed reports](http://forums.steamgames.com/forums/showthread.php?p=31259202) about this either working or not working.

Comment: Did you get the purple tint with config editing?

Comment: What if you don't have the game through Steam?

Comment: @GnomeSlicE: I was under the impression that this game *requires* Steam to play?  Regardless, both solutions still apply *(for the first one, just create a shortcut on the desktop and change its launch options instead)*